# How long will Playstation Plus offer free games to download?

Tags: ps3, playstation-plus

I'm thinking about getting the subscription but if it's gonna go away in a few months when the PS4 comes out, I'm not going to bother.  Does anyone know how long they will offer the free games?  (Xbox free games stop in 12/2013.)

Comment: Eventually it will likely end.  Most things do.  When that is, we can't really answer.  As it is now, Sony tends to wait until a few days into the month to announce the games for that month.

Comment: thank you for those that did help me answer this question, no thanks to the trolls that deemed it off topic.  I have never been to this site before and googled my question above, which brought me to this site.  Thanks to these trolls, i wont return.

Comment: how come my question is off topic when there are a lot of related questions down and to the right here???power trip...

Comment: While this question does involve gaming, it is more about future predictions.  We cannot speak on behalf of Sony (or any developer/publisher) so we cannot really answer this question definitively.  We can, as the answer here shows, relay information that Sony has made.  However, in the case where Sony has made no such claims, what are we to do?

Comment: Also, if you wish to discuss site policy, you are more than welcome to discuss with us in the meta: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/  Just know that getting down-voted, closed, or disagreed with is not a personal attack against you.  We are here to answer questions, key word being **answer**.

Answer (score 6):

Sony has made it clear they will continue the free games promotion with [PlayStation Plus](http://uk.playstation.com/psn/support/ps3/detail/linked285071/item285066/PlayStation-Plus-frequently-asked-questions/) and will have a free game every month (at least) for the PS4 (two the first month) and they will almost certainly continue the free games promotion for the PS3 and PS Vita as they have done for the last couple years.

Unlike Xbox Live Gold, PlayStation Plus *started* as a free games and discounts service, so it seems unlikely that they would cancel that aspect. But they certainly have not said anything indicating any future plans for canceling the free games portion.

Comment: Additional Note: Unlike the Xbox Live promotion, if you end your PS Plus subscription, you lose any games you did not pay for outside the subscription cost.

Comment: @Batophobia well sort of; you lose access to those games until the PS+ subscription resumes, at which point all PS+ games will work again.